# Python NET create generic dictionary with object as a type for the value

Tags: python, dictionary, generics, python.net

How do I create a dictionary of string, object in Python using Python NET?

C#

```
d = new Dictionary<string,object>() // works
```

Python

```
Dictionary [string, object] # TypeError : type(s) expected
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create it like that:

```
import clr
from System.Collections.Generic import Dictionary
from System import String
from System import Object
d = Dictionary[String, Object]()
d['Entry 1'] = 'test'
d['Entry 2'] = 12.3
d.Count # returns 2
```